# go random generator stops working after some calls

Tags: go, random

I want shuffle db ids so that none of the id refer to themselves, but with this piece of code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    seed := time.Now().UnixNano() & 999999999
    log.Print("seed: ", seed)
    rand.Seed(seed)
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}

    randomized := shufflePreventCollision(ordered)
    log.Print("Final Result")
    log.Print("ordered: ", ordered)
    log.Print("random:  ", randomized)

}

func shufflePreventCollision(ordered []int) []int {
    randomized := rand.Perm(len(ordered))
    for i, o := range ordered {
        if o == randomized[i] {
            log.Printf("Doing it again because ordered[%d] (%d) is == randomized[%d] (%d)", i, o, i, randomized[i])
            log.Print(ordered)
            log.Print(randomized)
            shufflePreventCollision(ordered)
        }
    }
    return randomized
}
```

I find a strange behaviour, when it runs often it at some point hangs and cannot find non-colliding sequences anymore. I tried 
`go build -o rand_example3 rand_example3.go && time (for i in $(seq 10000) ; do ./rand_example3 ; done)`

And it seems to never end. Am I missing some understanding here or is there really something fishy with math/rand?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Is that the exact code you're running? I think that maybe as the number of elements increases, the odds of a collision increases non-linearly, but that's just my intuition.

Comment: You're re-shuffling and re-scanning the entire list every time there's a single collision. I'm not at all surprised this takes forever.

Comment: Actually, from testing it looks like the odds of a collision are pretty linear.

Comment: Yes that is my code (for now at least) in my app i will probably groom it a little but the idea will be the same. It looks fine for the first couple of runs, then the number of collisions increase rapidly. from 1 or 2 to 10 or more, and when i do the loop above it doesn't end even when I let it run for an hour or so.

Comment: I haven't considered runtime complexity since the number of record to shuffle will hardly ever be above lets say 20

Comment: I can't recreate the issue. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/heyimalex/93fe27a8a88914cb61d61701edcfa23d) my code.

Answer (score 1):

> "With this piece of code, I want shuffle db ids so that none of the
>   ids refer to themselves. [Sometimes] it doesn't end even when I let it
>   run for an hour or so."

tl;dr There is a faster solution that is more than a thousand times faster.

---

Your code:

`slaxor.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    seed := time.Now().UnixNano() & 999999999
    log.Print("seed: ", seed)
    rand.Seed(seed)
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}

    randomized := shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered)
    log.Print("Final Result")
    log.Print("ordered: ", ordered)
    log.Print("random:  ", randomized)

}

func shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered []int) []int {
    randomized := rand.Perm(len(ordered))
    for i, o := range ordered {
        if o == randomized[i] {
            log.Printf("Doing it again because ordered[%d] (%d) is == randomized[%d] (%d)", i, o, i, randomized[i])
            log.Print(ordered)
            log.Print(randomized)
            shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered)
        }
    }
    return randomized
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/JI5rJGcAAz

It is not obvious how, or even if, the code fulfills its purpose.

The termination condition is probabalistic, not deterministic.

Let's leave aside the issue of whether the code fulfills its purpose.

---

This benchmark has been modified so that `stderr` is limited by the speed of the sink `/dev/null`, not a terminal.

`slaxor.bash`:

```
go build -o slaxor slaxor.go && time (for i in $(seq 10000) ; do ./slaxor 2> /dev/null ; done)
```

The benchmark measures the execution of a program and a single execution of the algorithm. The benchmark times are inconsistent because the pseudorandom seed value changes for each program execution. The benchmark sometimes "doesn't end even when I let it run for an hour or so."

There is a faster solution that runs and terminates in a few seconds, despite the program execution overhead.

`peterso.bash`:

```
go build -o peterso peterso.go && time (for i in $(seq 10000) ; do ./peterso 2> /dev/null ; done)
```

Output:

```
$ ./peterso.bash
real    0m5.290s
user    0m5.224s
sys     0m1.128s

$ ./peterso.bash
real    0m7.462s
user    0m7.109s
sys     0m1.922s
```

`peterso.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    seed := time.Now().UnixNano() & 999999999
    log.Print("seed: ", seed)
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}

    randomized := shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO(ordered)
    log.Print("Final Result")
    log.Print("ordered: ", ordered)
    log.Print("random:  ", randomized)
    if randomized == nil {
        err := "Shuffle Error!"
        fmt.Print(err)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

var r *rand.Rand

func isNoCollision(a, b []int) bool {
    if len(a) == len(b) {
        for i, ai := range a {
            if ai == b[i] {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO(ordered []int) []int {
    const guard = 4 * 1024 // deterministic, finite time
    for n := 1; n <= guard; n++ {
        randomized := r.Perm(len(ordered))
        if isNoCollision(ordered, randomized) {
            return randomized
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

The guard provides a deterministic, finite time, termination condition.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ZT-sfDW5Mi

---

Let's put aside the distorted program execution benchmarks, let's look at function execution times. Because this is important, the Go standard library has the `testing` package for testing and benchmarking functions.

Tests:

```
$ go test shuffle_test.go -v -count=1 -run=. -bench=!
=== RUN   TestTimeSlaxor
=== RUN   TestTimeSlaxor/1K
=== RUN   TestTimeSlaxor/2K
=== RUN   TestTimeSlaxor/3K
--- PASS: TestTimeSlaxor (13.78s)
    --- PASS: TestTimeSlaxor/1K (1.18s)
    --- PASS: TestTimeSlaxor/2K (1.27s)
    --- PASS: TestTimeSlaxor/3K (11.33s)
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO/1K
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO/2K
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO/3K
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO/1M
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO/2M
=== RUN   TestTimePeterSO/3M
--- PASS: TestTimePeterSO (6.57s)
    --- PASS: TestTimePeterSO/1K (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestTimePeterSO/2K (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestTimePeterSO/3K (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestTimePeterSO/1M (1.13s)
    --- PASS: TestTimePeterSO/2M (2.25s)
    --- PASS: TestTimePeterSO/3M (3.19s)
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  20.347s
$
```

In a fraction of the rapidly increasing time it takes to run 3K (3,000) iterations of `shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor`, 3M (3,000,000) iterations of `shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO` run, a more than thousand-fold improvement.

Benchmarks:

```
$ go test shuffle_test.go -v -count=1 -run=! -bench=.
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkTimePeterSO-8   1000000      1048 ns/op      434 B/op      2 allocs/op
BenchmarkTimeSlaxor-8      10000   2256271 ns/op   636894 B/op   3980 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  23.643s
$
```

It's easy to see that the `shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO` average per iteration cost of 1,000,000 iterations is small, 1,048 nanoseconds, especially when compared to only 10,000 iterations of `shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor` at 2,256,271 nanoseconds average per iteration.

Also, note the sparing use of memory by `shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO`, on average 2 allocations for a total allocation of 434 bytes per iteration, versus the profligate use of memory by `shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor`, on average 3,980 allocations for a total allocation of 636,894 bytes per iteration.

`shuffle_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "strconv"
    "testing"
)

func shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered []int) []int {
    randomized := rand.Perm(len(ordered))
    for i, o := range ordered {
        if o == randomized[i] {
            shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered)
        }
    }
    return randomized
}

var r *rand.Rand

func isNoCollision(a, b []int) bool {
    if len(a) == len(b) {
        for i, ai := range a {
            if ai == b[i] {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO(ordered []int) []int {
    const guard = 4 * 1024 // deterministic, finite time
    for n := 1; n <= guard; n++ {
        randomized := r.Perm(len(ordered))
        if isNoCollision(ordered, randomized) {
            return randomized
        }
    }
    return nil
}

const testSeed = int64(60309766)

func testTime(t *testing.T, ordered, randomized []int, shuffle func([]int) []int) {
    shuffled := shuffle(ordered)
    want := fmt.Sprintf("%v", randomized)
    got := fmt.Sprintf("%v", shuffled)
    if want != got {
        t.Errorf("Error:\n  from: %v\n  want: %s\n  got:  %s\n", ordered, want, got)
    }
}

func testTimeSlaxor(t *testing.T, n int) {
    rand.Seed(testSeed)
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
    randomized := []int{3, 1, 17, 15, 10, 16, 14, 19, 7, 6, 11, 2, 0, 12, 8, 18, 13, 4, 9, 5}
    testTime(t, ordered, randomized, shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor)
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered)
    }
}

func TestTimeSlaxor(t *testing.T) {
    for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
        n := 1000 * k
        t.Run(strconv.Itoa(k)+"K", func(t *testing.T) { testTimeSlaxor(t, n) })
    }
}

func testTimePeterSo(t *testing.T, n int) {
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(testSeed))
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
    randomized := []int{10, 7, 15, 14, 8, 6, 18, 17, 19, 11, 5, 16, 2, 12, 1, 13, 3, 0, 9, 4}
    testTime(t, ordered, randomized, shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO)
    for i := 1; i < n; i++ {
        shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO(ordered)
    }
}

func TestTimePeterSO(t *testing.T) {
    for k := 1; k <= 3; k++ {
        n := 1000 * k
        t.Run(strconv.Itoa(k)+"K", func(t *testing.T) { testTimePeterSo(t, n) })
    }
    for m := 1; m <= 3; m++ {
        n := 1000 * 1000 * m
        t.Run(strconv.Itoa(m)+"M", func(t *testing.T) { testTimePeterSo(t, n) })
    }
}

func benchTime(b *testing.B, ordered, randomized []int, shuffle func([]int) []int) {
    shuffled := shuffle(ordered)
    want := fmt.Sprintf("%v", randomized)
    got := fmt.Sprintf("%v", shuffled)
    if want != got {
        b.Errorf("Error:\n  from: %v\n  want: %s\n  got:  %s\n", ordered, want, got)
    }
}


func BenchmarkTimePeterSO(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(testSeed))
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
    randomized := []int{10, 7, 15, 14, 8, 6, 18, 17, 19, 11, 5, 16, 2, 12, 1, 13, 3, 0, 9, 4}
    benchTime(b, ordered, randomized, shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO)
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(testSeed))
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO(ordered)
    }
}


func BenchmarkTimeSlaxor(b *testing.B) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(testSeed))
    ordered := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19}
    randomized := []int{10, 7, 15, 14, 8, 6, 18, 17, 19, 11, 5, 16, 2, 12, 1, 13, 3, 0, 9, 4}
    benchTime(b, ordered, randomized, shufflePreventCollisionPeterSO)
    r = rand.New(rand.NewSource(testSeed))
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        shufflePreventCollisionSlaxor(ordered)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/ozazWGNZsu